# GoogleApiClient builder failing to build

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm implementing Google Smart Lock into an app, and I was having no trouble with the Api Client building before. In fact, I was finalizing some syntax changes and cleaning up the code (didn't even touch the code that initializes the Api Client), and my app now dies when `build()` is called on the Api Client builder, due to `abstract method zza`. Here is the error being displayed:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zze com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(android.content.Context, android.os.Looper, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzq, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener)"
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
```

I have no clue why it suddenly started failing, and I couldn't find any changes I made that would have caused this error. Why isn't that abstract method being overridden? It's nested deep inside the library so I don't understand how I could have affected it.

I wrapped the Google Api Client calls in a manager I named CredentialManager. Here is the code I used to initialize the client:

```
public CredentialManager(ContextProvider contextProvider) {
    mContextProvider = contextProvider;
    mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContextProvider.getContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.i(CredentialManager.TAG, "Api connected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Log.i(CredentialManager.TAG, "Connection suspended with status " + i);
                }
            })
            .enableAutoManage(mContextProvider.getContext(), connectionFailedResult -> {
                if (connectionFailedResult.hasResolution()) {
                    try {
                        connectionFailedResult.startResolutionForResult(
                                mContextProvider.getContext(),
                                CredentialManager.Codes.RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Unable to resolve, log error
                        Log.e(CredentialManager.TAG, "Resolution failed: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    //instead of displaying a dialog, just let the user continue and login manually.
                    Log.e(CredentialManager.TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionFailedResult.getErrorMessage());
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
            .build();
}
```

If you have any insight as to what is causing this error, please let me know. I've scoured the internet for anyone that has seen something like this before, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that some google play services dependencies had their versions updated and not the play-services-auth dependency used for google smart lock. The apk would compile fine, but crash when the Google Api Client was trying to initialize. The fix was to make all the versions the same, and invalidate cache + restart android studio, recompile, and run.